# Is ARC Memory Management of presentViewController:animated:completion: broken in iOS 6.x?

Tags: ios, ios5, ios6, modalviewcontroller

My view controller is presenting a view via the `presentViewController:animated:completion:` method. The view is presented fine.

Then I dismiss this view and re-present it and get the following crash:

```
*** -[WebBrowser isKindOfClass:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x1f640ac0
```

My code is using ARC. Here is the code of my WebBrowser class, a straightforward embedded browser.

WebBrowser.h:

```
@interface WebBrowser : ITViewController <UIWebViewDelegate, UIAlertViewDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *URL;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIActivityIndicatorView *spinner;

- (id)initWithURL:(NSString *)URL;
- (IBAction)dismissView:(id)sender;

@end
```

WebBrowser.m:

```
@implementation WebBrowser

- (id)initWithURL:(NSString *)URL_ {
    self = [super initWithNibName:@"MyNib" bundle:nil];
    if (self) {
        self.URL = URL_;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.webView.delegate = self;

    if (self.URL) {
        [self.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:self.URL]]];
    }
}

- (IBAction)dismissView:(id)sender {
    self.URL = nil;
    [self.webView stopLoading];
    self.webView.delegate = nil;
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}

// + some non-related web view delegate stuff 

@end
```

And finally here is how I present the view in my parent view controller:

```
WebBrowser *browser = [[WebBrowser alloc] initWithURL:URL];
[self presentViewController:browser animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

I'm running iOS 6 and compiling with ARC.

First I thought this bug was ARC related. Here is my original post:

### ORIGINAL POST

I've noticed crashes in my app with iOS 6.x when displaying modal view controllers and releasing it when it was working just fine with previous versions of iOS.

Blame me for not using ARC yet (it's my next big step on this project), but for instance, when displaying Game Center leaderboards with the following code, the following steps :

1. display the leaderboard
2. close the leaderboard
3. display the leaderboard again (PRECISION UPDATE: by running the same `showLeaderboard` shown below, ie displaying a **new** instance of `GKLeaderboardViewController`)

then, the following error happens

```
*** -[GKLeaderboardViewController isKindOfClass:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x17467120
```

This is my code:

```
- (void)showLeaderboard {
    if ([[GKLocalPlayer localPlayer] isAuthenticated]) {
        GKLeaderboardViewController *lb = [[GKLeaderboardViewController alloc] init];
        lb.category = ...;
        lb.leaderboardDelegate = self;
        self.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
        [self presentModalViewController:lb animated:YES];
        [lb release];
    } else {
        ...
    }
}

- (void)leaderboardViewControllerDidFinish:(GKLeaderboardViewController *)viewController{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

It turns out that removing the `[lb release]` instruction solves my problem and, again, that no such crash happens with iOS 5.x.

The same happens with the Game Center achievements view controller, or any other custom view controllers of mine being displayed with `presentModalViewController:`.

It also seems that replacing the deprecated-`presentModalViewController:` instruction by the new `presentViewController:animated:completion:` DOES NOT solve the problem.

Comment: What is the exact line that causes the error? add an exception breakpoint. Moreover, add a NSLog(@"Instance: %p", lb); before the presentModalViewController line, and post the result (the instance address of the NSLog and of the object causing the error)

Comment: What if you use `presentViewController:animated:completion:` and release `lb` in the completion handler?

Comment: Same kind of thing happening with ARC... @matt: thanks for the idea but this would sound like a nasty patch that could be problematic with future iOS versions, and now that I'm ARC-compliant, I shouldn't do it.

Comment: My first comment (Dec 2012 :-) is already valid: add an NSLog(@"Instance: %p", browser); after alloc-init the presenting browser and another in the dismiss method. Then, post the result. You should have 3 lines / instance address: 1- the first allocated-inited browser, 2- the first dismissed browser, 3- the second allocated browser. I suspect that your superclass (ITViewController) is giving you the same (deallocated) instance at every initWithNibName

Comment: @LombaX: here are the logs, init gives a different instance each time. 2013-03-07 17:45:08.259 iTooch[6200:907] init: 0x22542520
2013-03-07 17:45:09.706 iTooch[6200:907] dismiss: 0x22542520
2013-03-07 17:45:10.945 iTooch[6200:907] init: 0x2266bcb0
2013-03-07 17:45:10.947 iTooch[6200:907] *** -[WebBrowser isKindOfClass:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x22542520

Comment: another weird thing: if i add browser.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext; (or any other style that is not FullScreen) the app doesn't crash.

Comment: Ok. But now the problem in more clear: something is sending a message to the old instance AFTER you alloc-init the new one. You should try to understand who :-) Are you able to find the exact line of code causing it?

Comment: @LombaX: The debug stack is pretty clear about it : [self presentViewController:browser animated:YES completion:NULL]; is guilty.

Comment: maybe also worth mentioning, the view is presented when a UIActionSheet is shown. (as my WebView class works fine everywhere else in the app)

Comment: this seems a stupid question...but are you sure you don't have another variable (static, instance) called browser? The compiler would alert you...unless you disabled the warning. But it's simple to check...change "browser" with "aBrowser" :-)

Comment: Another important thing: are you sure that the dismiss animation is really completed when you call the second "present"? where do you call presentViewController?

Comment: Just to be sure...I tried with an empty project, only 2 vc's, one presenting and the other dismissing itself, and no errors.

Comment: Is your UIActionSheet being dismissed when you dismiss this controller?  I'm pretty sure UIActionSheets are also shown modally behind the scenes.  If dismissViewController is then being called, every modal in the stack will be released (another reason for using delegation).

Comment: @LombaX: a. yes, b. yes, c. it makes sense, something's weird...

Comment: I am a little confused by your code btw.  You are experiencing the crash because of a WebBrowser instance, and show the code for presenting that... but the _Old Post_ part of your question shows some LeaderBoard instance, being presented using the modal presentation style you mentioned in a comment on my answer.  So which views are being presented modally, and how many modals are you presenting on top of eachother?  Like I said, calling dismiss on one will call it on all of them.

Comment: if your present is being called after a dismiss, THAT might be your problem, although Cocoa usually calls out an error like 'A modal was presented while a dismissal was occuring' or something like that when that happens.  (this is what the 'completion' block is for, to call code AFTER the dismissal)

Comment: quick update: 2 new possible reasons out of the way : the action sheet and the delegate relationship between my view constroller and the UIWebView. I skipped both during tests and the song remains the same. My hair starts to fall. :)

Comment: If you don't want to use instruments :-P (which, I think, would take you to the real solution soon :-) I suggest you to try to exclude things --> try to comment the code in your viewDidLoad (so, don't initialize whe UIWebView, leave it blank) and check if something change. If not, try to exclude your UIActionSheet adding a temporary button on the "father" vc...ecc ecc

Comment: I have this exact same problem. It works fine in ios7 but not ios6. It drives me crasy.

Comment: @DirtyHenry Anything new about workaround?

Answer (score 1):

I see at least one possible problem:

```
[self.webView stopLoading];
self.webView.delegate = nil;
```

In general, it is safer to set `delegate` to `nil` before calling `stopLoading`.

Also, it is definitely safer to use `dismissViewControllerAnimated` it the way it is supposed to be used, that is, call it on the *presenting* controller. Although the documentation states the call is passed to the presenting controller, it's not a good idea to call a method on an object which is being deallocated inside the method.

```
- (IBAction)dismissView:(id)sender {
    // pass the event to the presenting controller
    // the presenting controller should call [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}

- (void)viewWillDissapear {
  [super viewWillDissapear];

   //no need to do this, it's done automatically in ARC
   //self.URL = nil;

   self.webView.delegate = nil;
   [self.webView stopLoading];
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I switched the instructions to make more sense logically speaking. It doesn't help with my problem though.

Comment: You make good points but it's not helping fixing my problem. Thanks though.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**

According to Apple's documentation you SHOULD be dismissing the viewcontroller from the parent (presenting) viewcontroller: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ModalViewControllers/ModalViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH111-SW14

"When it comes time to dismiss a presented view controller, the preferred approach is to let the presenting view controller dismiss it. In other words, whenever possible, the same view controller that presented the view controller should also take responsibility for dismissing it."

Also, can you please clear up which viewcontrollers are presenting which, and how many are overlayed on top of each other.  from apples docs:

"If you present several view controllers in succession, and thus build a stack of presented view controllers, calling this method on a view controller lower in the stack dismisses its immediate child view controller and all view controllers above that child on the stack. When this happens, only the top-most view is dismissed in an animated fashion; any intermediate view controllers are simply removed from the stack. The top-most view is dismissed using its modal transition style, which may differ from the styles used by other view controllers lower in the stack."

So if you think it might have anything to do with delegate methods coming from your webview, you should probably be unsubscribing the view from the delegate property/stopping the webview from loading in viewWillUnload, not in the dismissal IBAction, since that won't necessarily be called.

**I have edited this to make it more complete/clear**

You need to set the browser view to a instance variable with a strong property before presenting the view.  Then set it to nil after dismissing it.

First create a delegate protocol for Modals:

```
@protocol ModalViewDelegate
/**
 Delegation callback for when a modal has been dismissed
*/
- (void)modalDidDismiss:(UIViewController*)viewController;
@end
```

In your presenting view controllers interface, subscribe to the protocol:

```
@interface PresentingViewController <ModalViewDelegate>
@property (nonatomic,strong) WebBrowser *browserView;
@end
```

In your implementation when presenting the view:

```
WebBrowser *browser = [[WebBrowser alloc] initWithURL:URL];
browser.delegate = self
self.browserView = browser;
[self presentViewController:browser animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

In your WebBrowser interface:

```
@interface WebBrowser : ITViewController <UIWebViewDelegate, UIAlertViewDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *URL;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIActivityIndicatorView *spinner;

@property (nonatomic, weak) id <ModalViewDelegate> delegate;

- (id)initWithURL:(NSString *)URL;
- (IBAction)dismissView:(id)sender;

@end
```

In your WebBrowser implementation:

```
- (IBAction)dismissView:(id)sender {
    self.URL = nil;
    [self.webView stopLoading];
    self.webView.delegate = nil;
    [self.delegate didDismissBrowser:self];
}
```

And back in your parent view controller:

```
- (void)didDismissBrowser:(WebBrowser*)browser
{
    if (browser == self.browserView)
    {
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
        self.browserView = nil;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm convinced this would work (I actually reluctantly started implementing this workaround after posting my question) but I don't like it for 2 reasons: 1/ it doesn't help understanding what is wrong in my code 2/ since I can't dismiss from my WebView class, it means I need to create a WebView delegate protocol and all my client view controllers will need to implement the same "stupid" method that will dismiss the view and reset the property. It's not super DRY and not super convenient.

Comment: your last edit with the edition of a delegate for the webview supports my argument :)

Comment: This is the *correct* solution, i just made a domain-specific delegation protocol for your example use.  If you are concerned with being DRY (and you should be), then make it a ModalViewDelegate protocol, and change the method signature to didDismissModal:(UIViewController*)viewController.  You should be leveraging delegation.  Without the property, you have an autoreleased WebBrowser, which is having dealloc called on it during your dismiss call, hence the dealloced instance.

Comment: Apple's documentation supports my answer: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ModalViewControllers/ModalViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH111-SW14

Comment: this is not an ARC bug btw, it is doing exactly what it is supposed to.

Comment: I'm using the same code to present GameCenter views and other custom views of mine and it never crashes => the bug is either on my code, or in the SDK. If my code turns out clean, the SDK shouldn't call isMemberOfClass: in the  presentViewController:animated:completion: call if it doesn't make sure it keeps a valid reference on the previous presented controller.

Comment: @G.Shearer , this is a suggestion and a best practice. I don't think that it's causing the issue here. Note: the documentation is not saying you "should" but it's saying that it's "a preferred approach"

Comment: @LombaX in my experience anytime I have not followed this practice I experience Zombie calls like this question describes.  Not arguing and saying I am definitely correct, but I have found that it is smart to treat compiler warnings as errors, and Apple suggested guidelines as the _Word Of GOD_.

Comment: Now the answer finally makes sense. I have just added something similar to my answer. Calling a method on an object when the method releases the last reference to the object, is definitely dangerous.

Comment: Remember what I said 37 mins ago? "I'm convinced this would work". Well I implemented it and... it does not. Same behavior. (this talk was fun though)... I'll keep searching but as a workaround, i'll just add my `browser.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;` for now... :(

Comment: try to profile enabling zombies, it should give you more informations about the call tree...

Comment: my zombie mode is enabled already, that's how i know the crash happens during `presentViewController:animated:completion:`

Comment: Yes, but did you try to use it inside the Instruments app? it gives you more information to the exact (internal) line of code that is causing the problem. To be more clear: you can look at all calls before the "isKindOfClass:" call...maybe it can give us more informations :-) (when you find the zombie, click on the arrow and check all the calls)

Comment: btw, whoever downvoted me, thats pretty lame.  my code is following Apple best practices, if that doesn't solve this problem I'm sorry, but that didn't make my answer invalid or incorrect.

Comment: i.e. dont downvote someone for telling you to _Do the Right Thing_, you downvote them for completely off-topic and naive questions/answers.

Comment: It's a lost war...I usually get downvotes without reason, and without the "downvoter" explaining why...don't care too much about it :-)

Comment: I know, its not even that big of a pet peeve to me, i would just never downvote anyone without giving a reason, that goes against the entire *community* part of this site.  We are all sometimes wrong, and if you can't explain to me why, then neither of us learned anything.  The thing that bugs me is the brilliant coders I know that have never got a single upvote here, and therefore have ceased to contribute.

Comment: lol, i should have written that, the brilliant coders who are also designers, that constantly get downvoted for ABSOLUTELY CORRECT and succinct answers to how to use CSS3/HTML5/Javascript by jealous script kiddies

Comment: @G. Shearer: FYI, i'm not the one who downvoted you. And my further investigation tends to show that my class is fine and that the crash happens with any view controller that I'm trying to show with a full screen presentation style. So if my code has a problem, the parent view controller is more likely to be the problem.

Comment: @DirtyHenry i didnt think it was you.  Most downvotes are hit-and-run.  Just irritating lol

Comment: OK, I'm kind of giving up on this one... I think my parent view controller is managing some XIB files origins mixed with Storyboards and child view controllers. I'll just assume iOS 6 introduced this weird regression and that a good workaround for it is to present the modal view controller with a PageSheet format (or any other modal style other than full screen). Weird.

Comment: Thanks to both of you. I'm gonna sleep on it for a couple of days, and will come back with a complete answer including an overview of our talks for the benefit of the next viewers of this question.

Comment: This is recommended, but not required practice. Recommendation based on consideration that it's better if presenting controller dismisses presented one. The point is: presenting controller better knows how to dismiss presented one. No more.